# Oracle - How to find if the dates in a given list fall between a date range

Tags: oracle

I have a list of dates. 
The list will be passed as a java collection. 
The list is dynamic. I want to check if the dates in the list fall between my startDate and endDate, without using a stored proc, preferably.

I can iterate through the list and execute the query for each startDate/endDate pair of the list.
But is it possible to avoid iteration and do it all in one statement?

Something like

```
select * from myTable
where <datesInList> between startDate and endDate;
```

Is there a way in Oracle to do this?

Comment: Please provide more details, such as sample data in your table, sample list of dates and your expected output.

Comment: What kind of "list" is that? A PL/SQL collection? A list in your programming language? If yes, _which_ programming language? (Java, C#, ...)

Comment: List: '10-01-2015, 25-02-2015, 20-03-2015, 12-12-2016' and the dates to be compared are : 01-01-2014 and 01-01-2016

Comment: You can try to `select ... union` your dates to create a temp table and filter them just like you did with `between` clause, just changing the `<datesInList>` for the proper column name.

Comment: List will be passed as a java collection. I basically need to know if this possible using a query, without iterating the list in java and calling the query multiple times.

Comment: `for each startDate/endDate pair` "pairs" aren't a simple list. Do these "pairs" exist in a table?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the array into a table with the TABLE function and then use it in a SQL query. For example:

```
DECLARE
  v_dates sys.ODCIDateList := sys.ODCIDateList(TO_DATE('01-01-2001','DD-MM-RRRR'), 
                                               TO_DATE('01-02-2001','DD-MM-RRRR'),
                                               TO_DATE('01-03-2001','DD-MM-RRRR'),
                                               TO_DATE('01-04-2001','DD-MM-RRRR'));
  n NUMBER;  
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO n
  FROM TABLE(v_dates)
  WHERE COLUMN_VALUE NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;

  IF n > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('There''s ' || n || ' dates out of the range');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('All dates are in the range');
  END IF;    
END;
```

Comment: But still, I dont know ho wmany dates I will get in the list at a time. the input to ODCIDateList will be dynamic. I might have to loop through the list before I can convert it into v_dates.